# Autocad - How to match two files to the same scale

Tags: autocad

I am attempting to bring two images together in Autocad. In a nutshell, I am attempting to see how many of the smaller object I can fit into the larger one. When I copy the smaller pieces drawing, into the larger one, the smaller object appears way bigger in the viewport.

I need to know how to match the settings so that the when the images come on the same page, they are in correct proportion to one another.

[image]

Comment: at first I would suggest you make sure the UNITS are the same (or at least compatible)

Comment: They are. One is in mm and the other in cm

Comment: So AutoCAD will adjust the scales (i.e. scale up or down)

Comment: Have you tried to change the scale on one part to the other's part scale before pasting it?

Answer (score 0):

This is typically done by comparing each drawing file to find out what units each is in. Then by using the xref command to import on drawing on top of the other at origin specified or 0,0,0 on can scale the xref to match the units of one drawing or easier still just make sure the units in both drawings are the same such as Imperial default units to feet or inches.